# Can I simplify this case statement?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
switch (id.Substring(2, 2))
{
    case "00": return("14");
    case "01": return("19");
    case "02": return("19");
    case "03": return("19");
    case "1F": return("19");
    case "04": return("17");
    case "05": return("18");

}
```

Not sure about this but is there a way I can combine the "01", "02", "03" and "1F" into one?

Comment: the technical term for what you're looking for is "fall-through"

Comment: Fyi, `return` is not a function call so you don't need parentheses around the return value.

Comment: @KshitijMehta, C# doesn't support actual fall-through, only the specific case where only the item has any code.

Comment: @svick you're absolutely right. I was just introducing the term so that the OP can use it to do some further research

Comment: Why are you using `return` as a function/method? `return "19";` seems enough.

Answer (score 10):

```
    switch (id.Substring(2, 2))
    {
        case "00": return("14");
        case "01":
        case "02":
        case "03":
        case "1F": return("19");
        case "04": return("17");
        case "05": return("18");
    }
```

Basically, **as long as you don't add any code** (since fall-through is not supported), you can use the same outcome path for multiple test values.

Comment: performance: fine; practice... well, some people get very upset about `goto` - I'm pretty pragmatic and don't mind it, but there are usually tidier ways of writing it

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to create a dictionary with the case clauses (00, 01, etc) as keys and the values as 14, 19, etc.

Then switch on that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will add any value to the current answers, but in line with jfs - I would do the following...

```
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            result.Add("00","14");
            result.Add("01", "14");
            result.Add("02", "14");
            result.Add("03", "14");
            result.Add("1F", "19");
            result.Add("04", "17");
            result.Add("05", "18");

            return result[id.Substring(2, 2)];
```